# Gitlab job when tagging a release

Tags: git, gitlab, git-tag, gitlab-ci

So I have a Gitlab 8.1 instance running. Everything (nearly) is working as intended. I have deployment and build jobs that execute when I merge to different branches.

But I'd like to create a tarball every time I tag a new version of my project. But I can't seem to figure out the conditions required to trigger that sort of job.

I tag releases in version names (ie. v0.9.1-beta). And I have this in my .gitlab-ci.yml for the project:

```
build_release:
  script:
    - composer update
    - cd ..
    - tar cvzf $CI_BUILD_REF_NAME.tar.gz kin
stage: build
except:
  - production
  - develop
  - ^enhancement\/.*$
  - ^feature\/.*$
  - ^bugfix\/.*$
```

But it doesn't trigger. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually found solution myself that works pretty well. 
Given that all my release tags start with a 'v' followed by a number I was able to do this:

```
release:
script:
  - [BUNCH OF CLEANUP, REMOVAL OF FILES, ETC]
  - tar cvzf [APPNAME]_$CI_BUILD_REF_NAME.tar.gz  
stage: build
only:
  - /v[0-9].*$/
```

So that was, kinda awesome. :)

Answer (score 3):

`GitLab` gives you the `CI_BUILD_TAG` environment variable.  Simply add a test to your script that only creates the `tarball` when that environment variable is set.

```
before_script:
  - ... Some before code ...

stage:
  stage: stage
  script:
    - if [ -z "${CI_BUILD_TAG}" ]; then echo "Cowardly refusing to package an un-tagged commit."; exit 0; fi
    - ... Script Code Continues if didn't exit ...
```